# Confusion about steps of proof of rule C.

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

This question is from Introduction to Mathmatical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , page 83.[Introduction to Mathmatical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf)

I am somewhat confused about some steps of the proof of **rule C** in the book.Here are the steps I am confused about:

1."*We replace $d_k$ everywhere by a variable $z$ that does not occur in the proof*" I don't get intuitively how this line is justified syntactically.What does it mean by "does not occur in the proof"?. Also, what "proof" they are exactly talking about?

2.

> and, by Gen, 
> $$\Gamma , \mathscr C_1(d_1),...,\mathscr C_{k-1}(d_{k-1}) \vdash (\forall z)(\mathscr C_k(z) \to \mathscr B)$$
> Hence, by Exercise $2.32(d)$,
> $$\Gamma , \mathscr C_1(d_1),...,\mathscr C_{k-1}(d_{k-1}) \vdash (\exists y_k)\mathscr C_k(y_k) \to \mathscr B$$

I understand the use of  Exercise $2.32(d)$ .What I don't understand is , how they were able to replace $z$ with $y_k$ ?

3.

> But,
> $$\Gamma , \mathscr C_1(d_1),...,\mathscr C_{k-1}(d_{k-1}) \vdash (\exists y_k)\mathscr C_k(y_k)$$

I have no idea how this line is derived.

Comment: Page 90? Having said that, we have two *proof systems*: the "basic one, with MP and Gen as only rules of inference, and the corresponding $\vdash$ relation, and a new one, where we have three rules: the previous two plus Rile C, with $\vdash_C$.

Comment: The gist is Prop.2.10 (page 82): if $\Gamma \vdash_C B$, then $\Gamma \vdash B$. Thus, the prop will start from a *derivation* that uses Rule C and will produce a new derivation of the same end-formula that does **not** use it.

Comment: So, to replace $d$ everywhere means that we have the original proof $\vdash_C$ that uses an individual constant $d$ and we replace in the sequence of formulas (the derivation) every occurrence of $d$ with $z$ (new individual variable).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA About the page number, I mixed up the page number by the pdf page number.Sorry about that.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Regarding my 1. question , I found a similar post about it you answered [Confused by a step in the 'Rule C' proof in Mendelson's Logic Textbook](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872769/confused-by-a-step-in-the-rule-c-proof-in-mendelsons-logic-textbook?rq=1).In that post , you showed semantically the justtification of 1.Now,do I have to use completeness thoerems to prove it syntatically , or is there another way which don't require completeness theorems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To 1)*

We we have two proof systems: the "basic" one, with $\text {MP}$ and $\text {Gen}$ as only rules of inference, with the corresponding derivability relation $\vdash$, and a new one, where we have three rules: the previous two plus $\text {Rule C}$, with $⊢_C$.

**Prop.2.10** (page 82) says: if $Γ ⊢_C B$, then $Γ ⊢ B$. The proposition starts from a derivation that uses $\text {Rule C}$ and will produce a new derivation of the same end-formula that does not use it.

To replace $d$ everywhere means that, starting from the original $⊢_C$ derivation that uses the individual constant $d$, we have to replace in the sequence of formulas, starting from the first formula where $d$ occurs, every occurrence of $d$ with a new individual variable $z$.

We have to convince ourselves that this move is correct: $d$ is new, and thus no formulas in $\Gamma$ con use it.

Adding $d$, we can use it in instances of logical axioms; but the replacement of $d$ with $z$ will produce correct instances of logical axioms.

$\text {MP}$ is not affected; the only care must regards $\text {Gen}$, and here we have the proviso in the statement of $\text {Rule C}$.

In conclusion (assuming for simplicity that we have only one use of $\text {Rule C}$ in the derivation), starting from $\Gamma \vdash_C B$ we have: $\Gamma \vdash C(z) \to B$.

---

*To 2)*

Variable $z$ is new in the derivation; thus, it occurs nowhere in $\Gamma$ and we can "genaralize" it: $\Gamma \vdash \forall z (C(z) \to B)$.

Then we apply **Coroll. 2.32 (d)** to get: $\Gamma \vdash \exists z C(z) \to B$, because $z$ does not occur in $B$ [recall that $d$ does not occur in $B$].

But we can always "rename" a bound variable, provided that we do not violate the proviso regarding the *free for* condition [in a nutshell: $\forall x B(x) \vdash B(y) \vdash \forall z B(z)$].

Thus, we "restore" the original variable $y$ of $\exists y C(y)$ to get:

> $\Gamma \vdash \exists y C(y) \to B$.

---

*To 3)*

Now the final step. The original proof $\Gamma \vdash_C B$ used $\text {Rule C}$ because somewhere in the derivation there were a formula $\exists y C(y)$ and $\text {Rule C}$ was used to introduce the new step $C(d)$.

But if $\exists y C(y)$ occurred in some step of the original derivation, either (i) $\exists y C(y) \in \Gamma$ or (ii) $\Gamma \vdash \exists y C(y)$.

In both cases:

> $\Gamma \vdash \exists y C(y)$.

Thus, from:

n) $\Gamma \vdash \exists y C(y) \to B$,

and

n+1) $\Gamma \vdash \exists y C(y)$,

by $\text {MP}$ we have:

> n+2) $\Gamma \vdash B$.

Comment: Understood everything except ... How do I justify substituing $z$ for $d$ for axioms (A4) and (A5).Also I will never need completeness theorems for the proof of rule C, right?

Comment: @Prithubiswas - in what sense? (A4) is $\forall x A(x) \to A(t)$. Thus, if in the original derivation you have used $\forall x A(x) \to A(d)$ now you have to use $\forall x A(x) \to A(z)$.

Comment: "MP is not affected; the only care must regards Gen" Wait, why do we have to put care regards **Gen**  , isn't it as simple as justify substituting $z$ for $d$ for the MP case , or is there a special twist ?

Comment: @Prithubiswas - Rule C definition (page 82) point 3.

Comment: There is a line in the proof of rule C in the book (first paragraph of the proof in the book)
"_...and let $d_1,....,d_k$ be the corresponding new individual constants._" Does this mean also that $d_1 \neq d_2 \neq ... \neq d_{k-1} \neq d_k$ 
?

Comment: @Prithubiswas - of course YES. The def of Rule C asks for "$d$ new". Thus, the first use of Rule C introduce $d_1$ new; with a second use of Rule C you cannot use it again (because it is nor more new) so you have to introduce $d_2$ that must be new, and thus **different** from $d_1$.

Comment: What if in the deduction of $\Gamma \vdash_C \mathscr B$ , I did not use any wf from $\Gamma$ , can I still use a constant $d_1$ for rule C if $d_1$ is in one of the wfs in $\Gamma$ ?

Comment: New means... new. Of course, if a premise $\sigma \in \Gamma$ is not used at all, the derivation $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ is the same of $\Gamma \setminus \{ \sigma \} \vdash \varphi$ and thus, if $d$ occurred **only** in $\sigma$, it will be new for $\Gamma \setminus \{ \sigma \} \vdash \varphi$.

Comment: Thanks for your clearcut answer on this . The reason I am asking this extra question is to sure about what I am dealing with when I am trying to understand rule C  fully.Hope you did not mind for asking too many questions.

Comment: @Prithubiswas - no problem :-) Maybe you have to try to understand the way math log is used: it is a precise mathematical model of mathematical reasoning. Thus, it is aimed at being fully formal/explicit and (in principle) to be used by a machine; and today we have proof assistants that are mechanical. Thus the need for being formal and explicit. In real life mathematics no one will have use many instances of Rule C in a single proof and every trained mathematician is perfectly capable of managing "temporary constants" as needed by Rule C avoiding fallacies.