# Help in understanding this proof in Mendelson

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, metalogic

Am new to Logic, and am having difficulty with this proof of Proposition 2.10 of Mendelson's Book "Introduction to Logic". The proposition describes a rule termed "Rule C", whereby given a well-formed formula (wff) $\mathcal{B}(x)$, with free variable $x$, Rule C permits passing from $(\exists x)(\mathcal{B}(x))$ to $\mathcal{B}(b)$ where $b$ is a constant (aka Existential Instantiation in other books).

Just to make this post self-contained, I will describe *Rule C deductions* in detail. Given a set of hypothesis $\Gamma$, a Rule C deduction to $\mathcal{B}$ is denoted as $\Gamma \vdash_C \mathcal{B}$, whereby the deduction involves a sequence of wffs $\mathcal{D}_1,...,\mathcal{D}_n$ with $\mathcal{D}_n=\mathcal{B}$, and where:

1. For each $i < n$, $\mathcal{D}_i$ is either: (i) an axiom, (ii) a hypothesis in $\Gamma$, (iii) a result of Modus Ponens or Generalization from preceding wffs in the deduction, or (iv) if there is a preceding wf $(\exists x) \mathcal{C}(x)$, and $\mathcal{D}_i=\mathcal{C}(d)$ with $d$ a constant.
2. $\mathcal{B}$ has no constants introduced from the deduction
3. Universal Generalization is not made using a variable that is free in some $(\exists x)\mathcal{C}(x)$ to which rule C was applied.

Now, let $\vdash$ represent the usual logical implication. We have the ff.

**Proposition 2.10:** If $\Gamma \vdash_C \mathcal{B}$, then $\Gamma \vdash \mathcal{B}$

**Proof.** Let $(\exists y_1)\mathcal{C}_1(y_1),...,(\exists y_k)\mathcal{C}_k(y_k)$ be wffs in order of occurence to which Rule C is applied in the proof of $\Gamma \vdash_C \mathcal{B}$, and let $d_1,...,d_k$ be new constants introduced on each application of Rule C. Then $\Gamma, \mathcal{C}_1(d_1),...,\mathcal{C}_k(d_k) \vdash \mathcal{B}$. Using a basic result of deductions, we also have $\Gamma, \mathcal{C}_1(d_1),..., \mathcal{C}_{k-1}(d_{k-1}) \vdash \mathcal{C}_k(d_k) \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$. Now, replace $d_k$ everywhere by a variable $z$ that does not occur in the proof so that $\Gamma, \mathcal{C}_1(d_1),..., \mathcal{C}_{k-1}(d_{k-1}) \vdash \mathcal{C}_k(z) \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$. Applying Universal Generalization aftewards, we also have $\Gamma, \mathcal{C}_1(d_1),..., \mathcal{C}_{k-1}(d_{k-1}) \vdash (\forall z) (\mathcal{C}_k(z) \rightarrow \mathcal{B})$ *(for brevity, I will omit the rest of the proof from this point on...)*

What is confusing me is the part in the proof whereby the introduced constant $d_k$ is substituted by a variable $z$, and for which Universal Generalization is subsequently applied to arrive at the term $(\forall z) (\mathcal{C}_k(z) \rightarrow \mathcal{B})$

This seems to make the following deduction possible. For instance, let $\Gamma:=\{\exists x (x < 1)\}$, where $[x < 1]$ is a unary predicate with $1$ as a constant. We have the following:

1. $(\exists x)(x < 1)$ - hypothesis
2. $d < 1$ - application of Rule C
3. $z < 1$ - introduction of new variable $z$ which replaces $d$ (as done in the proof)
4. $(\forall z)(z < 1)$ - Universal Generalization (as done in the proof)

This is obviously not correct. What am I missing in my understanding of the proof ?

Comment: No, the proof is: $\exists x (x < 1)$ and $\Gamma, (d < 1) \vdash B$. Then we have $\Gamma \vdash (z < 1 \to B)$, from which $\Gamma \vdash \forall z (z < 1 \to B)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, okay I see the duplicate. Thanks for that. I understand the logic behind the introduction for $z$ since $(\exists x)\mathcal{C}(x)$ has already been proved, as you showed in your prior answer. 

What I don't understand is the Universal Generalization step (which is not clarified in the prior post). If UG is allowed, isn't the above deduction allowed as well ? or is UG allowed only if there's a term $\rightarrow B$ ? ... By the way, this same reasoning is used in Lemma 2.15 of Mendelson where no $\rightarrow B$ term occurs ..

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, the proof above is not meant to be part of the deduction in $\Gamma \rightarrow B$, but as a separate theory / deduction which shows $\Gamma:=(\exists x)(x <1) \vdash (\forall x)(x <1)$ which is not true

Comment: No, the difference is that $C(z)$ is moved to the right of $\vdash$ and we know that $z$ does not occur to the right of it. In this case we can generalize it, because "from $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ to $\Gamma \vdash \forall z \varphi$" is sound, **provided that** $z$ is not *free* in $\Gamma$.

Comment: Following your approach, we have $\exists x (x < 1)$ and something like: $\Gamma, (d <1) \vdash (d < 1)$, from which $\Gamma \vdash (d < 1 \to d < 1)$ and thus $\Gamma \vdash \forall x (x < 1 \to x < 1)$.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115567/confusion-about-steps-of-proof-of-rule-c) for more details.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ok that clears it up. thank you !

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, just a follow up question, what is meant by a variable being free in $\Gamma$ ? Suppose that $(\exists x)C(x) \in \Gamma$ and in some proof, we have that $x$ is substituted by a new constant $d$ and $d$ is substituted by a new variable $z$. Is $z$ free in $\Gamma$ ?

Comment: Mendelson, page 49.